# not a valid sha512_crypt hash Python Flask Error

Tags: python, flask, sha256

Hey for some reasons I get this error `not a valid sha512_crypt hash`everytime I try to login on my login page.

Piece of Register page:

```
                username = request.form['username']
                password = sha512_crypt.encrypt((str(request.form['password'])))
                email = request.form['email']

                cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name,password,email) VALUES (?,?,?)",(username,password,email)
```

Piece of my login Page:

```
data = cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name= ?", (request.form['username'],))

                data = cur.fetchone()[0]

                if sha512_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], data):
                    session['logged_in'] = True
                    session

                  #etc #etc #etc
```

So when I fill in a username and password from my DB I get an error: 
`not a valid sha512_crypt hash`
In my DB there are encrypted passwords, so my sha256 encryption works theoretically.

Comment: What does `data` look like? Can you make an account with the password `password` and post the hash?

Comment: What do you mean?
`data`is just that SQL Query and that `fetchone()`

Comment: How do you know `data` contains a valid hash?

Comment: I'm assuming it contains a valid hash, because it selects it from my database.

Comment: I know, but can you just post what `repr(data)` shows and the corresponding password so that you can actually be sure that you're storing a valid password hash in your database?

Comment: Like that? `data = cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name= ?", (request.form['username'],))
                data = cur.fetchone()[0]
                repr(data)`

Comment: Yes, that would work. Make a new account with the password `password` and see what the corresponding hash is.

Comment: I get a new error now `'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable`.
In my DB there is: http://prntscr.com/cyeht8

Comment: That probably means that your code now works and gets past the `if sha512_crypt.verify(...)` line, but you have another error later on.

Comment: @zaph: `sha512_crypt` isn't just `sha512`: https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html

Comment: Good naming can be so helpful, `sha512_crypt` not so much. Thx for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have password hashes in your database created with both `sha256_crypt` and `sha512_crypt`, but you're using `sha512_crypt` to verify both both. That won't work.

Either re-create the passwords for users with hashes created with `sha256_crypt` (they start with `$5$`), or use `passlib.apps.custom_app_context`, which verifies both. Here's an example from [the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/new_app_quickstart.html#really-quick-start):

```
# import the context under an app-specific name (so it can easily be replaced later)
from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context

# encrypting a password...
hash = pwd_context.encrypt("somepass")

# verifying a password...
ok = pwd_context.verify("somepass", hash)
```

Comment: I get 2 errors now. 
`hash could not be identified`

Comment: and: `'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable`

Comment: @Julian: Without context, those errors are meaningless. Please distill the problematic code to be somewhat self-contained: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Changed the sha512 encryption to the passlib.apps. thing.
`if pwd_context.verify(request.form['password'], data):`
and in my user registration form: `password = pwd_context.encrypt((str(request.form['password'])))`
Now somehow I managed to get my flash, that flashes ("Succesfully logged in") but with that it still gives me an error. This is what I get after I press login: `Successfully logged in 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
`
in my Code for my login page, I've put a `return redirect(url_for(hello))` after the flash.

Comment: i changed mine from encrypt to hash